# Conversion drop-off by switching sites

Tags: e-commerce

I work for a website where consumers can search and browse theatrical events. Due to our partnership agreements, ticket purchasing happens on our partner sites.

We'd like to propose that we use partner data feeds so that purchasing happens on our site instead.

Have there been any cases, studies, or articles that demonstrate that splitting a shopping + purchase experience across sites causes drop-off or is generally detrimental?

Answer (score 1):

If the website they are moving to is perceived as

- more secure, or
- more authoritative

then conversions are likely to increase. [Example is Paypal](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48255/does-adding-paypal-to-a-checkout-increase-conversion-rate)

In your specific case if the partner is a better known ticket office or the actual service provider itself (i.e. a theatre) then the user will know everything is "official" and unlikely to have any hitches.  So the users will be more confident, and more likely to follow through. In turn conversions may decrease if user is given a single site purchase experiance. Perceived safety can often trump small UX workflow gains.

Answer (score 0):

A user should always have a sense of home when using any software, web or otherwise. If you rely on other sites for anything, you leave your user's experience in the hands of others.  This is a great user testing case.  I recommend setting up test scenario for a few people and see how they react.  Ask for their honest feedback and then weigh the results. There is plenty of research in this domain.  However, this is an instance where you can generate your own data easily enough.

Answer (score -1):

I think that keeping users on one site always leads to a more convenient, less confusing experience, I believe that whenever possible and logical, the user experience should be kept in one place. Think about a site like amazon, fandango or ticketmaster. You go to the site, you shop for what you want you buy it, and then you are done, you never left the site, so the next time you want to buy something, you go back to that site. If the website was constantly taking you to different sites to make the purchases, you would eventually just go to those sites instead. It would be different of course if your site was just a search engine, but when it comes to people entering credit card info on the internet, people get nervous, and redirecting them to different sites only serves to make them more nervous.